# Differences in developing Android kotlin apps vs Android Java apps on the command line (without android studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, command-line

I am trying to compile a sample Android application ([original source](https://medium.com/@authmane512/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676)) written in kotlin on the command line.

The Java version of it compiles without a problem.

This is the file hierarchy layout:

```
.
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── bin
├── mykey.keystore
├── obj
│   └── com
│       └── example
│           └── helloandroid
├── res
│   ├── drawable
│   ├── layout
│   │   └── activity_main.xml
│   └── values
│       └── strings.xml
└── src
    └── com
        └── example
            └── helloandroid
                ├── MainActivity.java
                └── MainActivity.kt
```

If I compile the Java version I issue the following commands:

1. `aapt package -f -m -J ./src -M ./AndroidManifest.xml -S ./res -I /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar`
2. `javac -d obj -classpath src -bootclasspath /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar src/com/example/helloandroid/*.java`
3. `dx --dex --output=./bin/classes.dex ./obj`
4. `aapt package -f -m -F ./bin/hello.unaligned.apk -M ./AndroidManifest.xml -S ./res -I /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar`
5. `cp ./bin/classes.dex .`
6. `aapt add ./bin/hello.unaligned.apk classes.dex`
7. `apksigner sign --ks mykey.keystore ./bin/hello.apk`
8. Install the App via adb on a Google Pixel and it works.

Now the question is: How would I replicate that "workflow" with kotlin?

As far as I understand the only steps I need to change are the first two. I need to generate a `R.kt` file, because otherwise `R` is undefined and step two where I actually compile the sources to classes. After that there should be no difference ?

I don't want to use gradle. I just want to understand how I can use the command line utils.

Thanks in advance for any helpful answer :D

**EDIT:** The Source is completely in Kotlin, not a mix of Java+Kotlin as shkschneider suggested. The MainActivity.java is essentially the same Code as MainActivity.kt I just want to switch to Kotlin.

Comment: Should we assume the code is all Kotlin and not a mix of Java+Kotlin?

Comment: I don't know the precise commands to build for Android without Gradle, but I just wanted to point out `kolinc` which is its CLI compiler for reference https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html

Comment: I have read that Documentation and TBH it doesn't help that much, because my problem is specific to Android App Compilation on the cmd line. Compiling standalone Kotlin Apps is not a problem. I tried https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html to generate R.kt, but i could not get it to work, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem. The `R.kt` file has to be generated via the JetBrains IDE from the `R.java` file, because they don't provide a standalone tool. If someone knows one please share a link :D